# Need an Example for Building Django Form Fields with Multiple Columns

Tags: python, django, forms

I am building a Django form where each field can have multiple columns input from users. For example, let user to input the body weight each week

```
        week1 week2 week3 week4
weight   120   125   123   130
```

My original code is simplified like this:

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
     weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

forms.py

```
class PersonCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Person
```

views.py

```
class PersonCreateView(CreateView):
     model = Person
     template_name = 'add_person.html'
     form_class = PersonCreateForm
```

From the django docs, the MultiValueField seems to be needed? Or formset factory? (Please give an example) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield

Comment: Could you explain why this one is on hold? There are many questions asking for examples like uploading files, etc. which are highly voted.

Comment: I delete the paragraph of 'better' package  so there will be no argument in this question. Now it is a pure programming question. Could you please cancel the on-hold? I am waiting for others to answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I would go about this the way you are currently.  Rather than having many different "weeks" as columns it makes more sense to have a single "week" column and put each entry as its own row. Imagine having people input their weight every week for 5 years. This would give you 260 column!

I would instead try something like this:

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User) #many to one relationship to User table
    week = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

By designing your database this way you can quickly and easily execute a variety of queries such as: query each individual and see all of their data, get each user for a specific week.

views.py

```
current_user = request.user
Person.objects.filter(user=current_user)

    OR

current_user = request.user
Person.objects.filter(week=4)
```

Comment: The idea of storing the past data is great. Do you mean keep one row 'week' whose value is filled by the user? Will this be able to display multiple rows automatically like week1, week2, week3, etc?

Comment: Each entry (row) in the database would only relate to 1 specific week.  So example data from above might be:

user_id: 4 (automatically a column in the table when you use a ForiegnKey)
week: 1
weight: 145

You could easily create a form that takes 1 entry at a time or one that a user can input the past 10+ weeks (the number doesn't matter).  Having it display multiple weeks would be as easy as using my first query from above and passing the result to your template where you can handle displaying all of that data from every week.

Comment: Does this allow users to input, say 10 weeks' data at once? That is, HTML can render 10 rows for last 10 weeks?

Comment: Yeah. You would just build a database entry for each week when you process the input from the user. Depending on the implementation this might be useful for you as well: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Comment: If you were happy with my answer please accept and upvote :-)

Comment: I am still trying to understand. If you put only one field for the week, will user's later input e.g. week2 overwrite existing week e.g.week1's data? Or it will create a new object each week? It is preferred to have a list to storing all week's data for one person. Waiting for more answers, however, the question is put on-hold.

Comment: There are a variety of ways to handle the situation you are talking about. You can create a `<select>` in the HTML so the user can choose the week. A simple loop that checks which weeks have been input by the user (pass the results from a User query to the template) can prevent the user from double inputting data (along with form validation). To answer your question though, it is up to you whether you want the user to override previous entries or enter new ones.  What I laid out for you is standard design for relational databases. It may be good to read some information on database design.

Comment: Any resource recommended for database design? I will wait for a while and accept your answer if nothing better comes up.

Comment: Don't mind the name of the tutorial, it is a pretty good beginners tutorial. Good luck!! http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/relational-databases-for-dummies--net-30244